# Resizing nodes in SpriteKit view according with diifferent display's size

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create an universal application with spriteKit view.
But the iPad display is bigger tha iPhone display!

1) How can I positioning the nodes that they resizing according to the display dimensions? I mean when I add a nodes for iPhone screen I don't want that on iPad the dimension of this node is equal to the dimension of on iPhone, I want have the same nodes with differents sizes for each different screen.

2) And also How can I positionig this nodes for differents display?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

first set a automatic margin for your app:

```
var gameArea: CGRect

override init(size: CGSize) {

    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
    gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

    super.init(size: size)
}
```

Then you can implement your SKNode

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Player
player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy
player.constraints = [SKConstraint.positionX(SKRange(lowerLimit: gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2, upperLimit: gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2))]`
```

Comment: Thank you, but I mean color sprites not nodes.

Comment: this is the almost the same as .aspectFit but with more work

Answer (score 0):

> I want have the same nodes with differents sizes for each different
>   screen.

If I understand what you want, here my answer:

You have two options:

1 - https://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1

2 - programmatically resizing:

```
// code in objc

// defines global
#define IS_IPAD      ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
#define IS_IPHONE    ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )

#define SCALE_FACTOR ( IS_IPAD ? 2 : 1 ) // what ever you want

// usage in  the code
sprite.size = CGSizeMake(width * SCALE_FACTOR, height * SCALE_FACTOR);  

// etc...
```

---

**EDIT:**

The position is always relative to the parent. The anchor points are also important here. Here an example how to add a label **direct to the scene**. The label position is **top middle**:

```
func addBestScoreLabel(bestScore: Int) {
        let bestScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

        bestScoreLabel.text = "Best Score: " + String(bestScore)
        bestScoreLabel.fontSize = 20 // what ever
        bestScoreLabel.fontColor = .red // what ever
        bestScoreLabel.zPosition = 10 // what ever
        bestScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height - bestScoreLabel.frame.height)

        // add the label to the scene
        self.addChild(bestScoreLabel)
    }

// call the function
addBestScoreLabel(bestScore: 1234)
```

Comment: First you create your sprite, right? After that you give it a size. When you do that, you can consider the scale factor depending on the device.

Comment: Can you write code please ? this is my code:  bestScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 256, y: self.frame.height / 256 + self.bestScoreLabel.frame.width / 3 - 20)
            
            bestScoreLabel.scale(to: CGSize(width: self.frame.width - 30, height: self.frame.width / 2)) thank a lot

Comment: This is a terrible approach that requires a lot of math, better off using scale mode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you mean my approach is terrible? can you explain please?

Comment: Your approach requires to do math on everything,  meaning you can typo bugs, get math done wrong, etc.  the scalemode is designed in a way where you do not have to do any of this.  You design for 1 size, and then at the end of the pipeline, it gets scaled once

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That was an example with scale=1 and scale=2. But I think my approach is more flexible than the scale mode. What I mean is, I can expand my macro as I want: 
`#define SCALE_FACTOR ( IS_IPAD ? 1 : (IS_IPHONEX ? 0.9 : (IS_IPHONE5 ? 0.6 : (IS_IPHONE4 ? 0.5 : 0.8) ) ) )`
This way I’m very flexible with the sprite/image sizes. The scale mode has always the same value. If I have an Image with size 128x128 then I can use my scale macro to create a sprite with the same image in various sizes based on the device screen size. Agree? Or do you have a better solution?

Comment: Yes. I can create three images image.png, image@2.png and image@3.png for each device. But I think, I can use this macro, since I use it only when I create a sprite.

Comment: Do not confuse the retina graphics for scaleMode.  ScaleMode has 4 options, 3 of which keep your scene size static.  So I can make a scene that 256x240 to emulate a retro style looking game, and then on different devices it will fill the screen, but retain the proper scene size.  It eliminates having to so all the math,  because like i said, the scaling happens at the end of the pipeline in one step, where you are scaling throughout the entire pipeline, which becomes error prone due to the excess work.